# Flash Builder variable across multiple functions in one view

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air

I am building my first app in Flash Builder, and am trying to import SQL data from OSTickets into a handheld format for my crew chiefs. The dilemma is as follows:

The fololwing function generates the base ticket info, including the truck ID:

```
    protected function getOst_ticketByID(itemID:int):void
        {
        getOst_ticketByIDResult.token = ostticketService.getOst_ticketByID(itemID);
        }
```

The problem is that OSTickets breaks the truck's id number and the actual radio call number into two separate tables. I want to use the truckID field indicated below in another function to query the truck number table for additional info within the same view:

```
    <s:Label text="{getOst_ticketByIDResult.lastResult.truckID}"/>
```

How can this specific field be nested in another function within the same field to get the information from the second table (getOst_truck_numberByID, for reference)?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you asking a question about data storage in a database; or object storage in a Flex UI?  OR something totally different?

Comment: And how can you have a function within a field?